# Error inserting row into MS Access DB programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I have a Microsoft Access database (*.mdb file) which I need to insert rows into programmatically (in C#).  I have no control over this access file - it is a pre-existing file which I need to work with.

When I attempt this using the code below, a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException is thrown.  The message in that exception contains the same text that has been defined as the validation text for one of the fields (Customer).  So on the surface, the exception message would indicate that I'm either not providing a required field, or that I'm providing an invalid value for that field.

However, the value I'm passing in should be Ok.  Certainly, inserting a row with the same values inside of Access itself works fine.

The code I'm using is:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Temp\\Indial_Reg.mdb;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Indial Register] ([Exchange],[Customer]) Values ('WISB/SYRA','TEST')", connection))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, when I open Microsoft Access and issue the exact same INSERT INTO command inside the access script editor, the insertion works flawlessly.

In case it is relevant, the validation rule which has been defined on the Customer field is :
Like "*[A-Z]*"

Am I using the wrong connection string?  Wrong provider driver?
Can anyone point me towards something I'm doing wrong in the code?
I'm at my wits end.  Any assistance would be fantastic.

My environment is: Windows 7 32 bit.  I have MS Access 2007 installed.
My code is running in Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried with sample data and found no problem in the code. Can you send the db file so as to try?

Comment: How is the Validation rule set as?

Comment: Can you show the Validation string?

Comment: I've put the Validation rule and now i've got the same problem as you

Comment: @Sayka - thanks for your response.  The validation rule is actually: Like "<asterisk>[A-Z]<asterisk>"  (the asterisks in my original question didn't get into the text)

Comment: @Sayka - If you're seeing the same issue, does that mean that it is failing for you programmatically, but working when done inside of Access?

Comment: Yes. Just as same as yours. But now got solution

Comment: You said you can't change the validation rule on file right?

Comment: Correct.  Changing the validation rule would be very much a last resort.

Comment: I've tried changing it. Now working flawlessly.

Comment: I mean not removing. But just altering a little bit to accept from c sharp. But still the rule will be as it is

Comment: You still cant add numbers or symbols from c sharp or access

Comment: How abt that? Can u?

Comment: I am not the owner of the file - and so any changes to the mdb file may be extremely difficult.  I'd be interested to hear what you discovered - but ultimately would love to have a c# solution.

Comment: I'm also extremely curious to know what the problem is... why the same insert script works inside of Access but not from Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the validation rule that you are having now doesn't permit value from your application.

The validation rule you required is this :

```
Like "%[A-Z]" Or Like "*[A-Z]"
```

The Rule "%[A-Z]" will permit characters between A to Z from application

And

The Rule "*[A-Z]" permits that from Access

Comment: Thanks Sayka.  I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require changes to the access file - but at least this reveals that validation rules behave differently between Access and external (Jet) drivers.  I will accept this answer if no "code-only" solution is offered.

Comment: And interestingly, I discovered that any changes to the validation rules require Access to 'revalidate' the existing data against the new rules.  It turns out that from the Access datasheet view, the rules are NEVER respected.  It is already full of data which does not conform to the existing rules!

Comment: But isn't there a revalidating option in access, that prompts when you change rule?

Comment: Yes exactly!  When I tried changing the rule, I was prompted that way.  But revalidation fails against the existing data.  I even found that removing and then re-adding the original rule, it still failed.  That was when I discovered that the existing data ALREADY doesn't conform to the EXISTING rule.  So unless I'm missing something obvious, it appears that Access validation rules are completely useless and not always adhered to.

Comment: Think it from the developer side. That much only they can do. I've coded for SQLite like database application, in which also things were like that

Comment: I actually don't think what I've seen is acceptable.  Access has a validation rule which it doesn't even respect itself.  I've now found that I can type *anything* into that field from within Access... nothing I provide is ever refused.  Only external access seems to care about validation.